# Baby-sitting bash script using DVD drive

Tags: bash, linux

This is the script I wrote to make an automated POC baby-sitter in 5 lines.

I first found this on a GIF or meme site and thought of making a POC script that does the same.

[image: Automated babysitting using Linux]

```
#How Linux users babysit
while : 
do
    eject
    eject -t
done
```

I don't know aything about bash. So, I want improvements.

You can find the origin and the script at
https://linuxandstuff.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/messing-with-the-dvd-drive-in-command-line/

Comment: Add some delay to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days a `-T` (toggle) argument exists. That allows us to make this a lot neater:

```
watch -n0 eject -T
```

You can alter the delay between rocks by changing the `-n0` argument.

> watch is used to run any designated command at regular intervals.

http://www.linfo.org/watch.html